# Azure blocklist contains 2 committed blocks but the result blob only shows the first block

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am using rest api of azure tu put block and also put block list, the operations finished successfully. I checked this with get method of this url https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/container/myblobname?comp=blocklist
the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BlockList>
    <CommittedBlocks>
        <Block>
            <Name>MjAyMy0wNy0xM1QxNTo0Mjo0MS4xM</Name>
            <Size>1048057</Size>
        </Block>
        <Block>
            <Name>MjAyMy0wNy0xM1QxNTo0MzoxMC44M</Name>
            <Size>460893</Size>
        </Block>
    </CommittedBlocks>
</BlockList>
```

These 2 blocks are related to a video file. my problem is that when I use the url (https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/container/myblobname) to get whole video it just return first block so the second one is missing. where is the problem?
request details
[image]

Updated: here is my code

```
export const uploadLongFile = async (param: any) => {
  const {path, filename, mime} = param;
  const blockSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // 1MB
  const fileSize = param?.size;
  const blockCount = Math.ceil(fileSize / blockSize);
  const sasContainerUri =  Config.CONTAINER_URI;
  const customBlobName = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
  const fileExtension = (filename ?? path).split('.').pop();
  const newFileName = `${customBlobName}.${fileExtension}`;
  const container = 'images';
  const assetPath = `${sasContainerUri}/${container}/${newFileName}`;
  const sasToken = Config.SAS_TOKEN; // you may need to play with other html verbs in this string e.g., `sp`, `ss` e.t.c.
  const blockIds: any[] = [];
  const videoChunks: any[] = [];
  const timeInterval = param?.duration / 1000 / blockCount;
  const chunks = await TrimWithIntervalVideo(path, timeInterval);// Trim video into blockCount chunks
  let totalSize = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < blockCount; i++) {
    let dataString = encodeURIComponent(encode(new Date().toISOString()));
    blockIds.push(dataString);
    let info = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.stat(videoChunks[i]);
    let chunkPath =
      i < 10
        ? `${chunks?.url}00${i}.${chunks?.ext}`
        : i < 100
        ? `${chunks?.url}0${i}.${chunks?.ext}`
        : `${chunks?.url}${i}.${chunks?.ext}`;
    videoChunks.push(chunkPath);
    totalSize += info.size;
    await stageBlock(
      blockIds[i],
      videoChunks[i],
      `${assetPath}?${sasToken}`,
      info?.size,
    );
    if (i === blockCount - 1) {
      commitBlockList(blockIds, totalSize, `${assetPath}?${sasToken}`);
    }
  }
};
const stageBlock = async (
  blockId?: any,
  chunk?: any,
  url?: any,
  length?: any,
) => {
  const res = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fetch(
    'PUT',
    `${url}&comp=block&blockid=${blockId}`,
    {
      'x-ms-date': new Date().toUTCString(),
      'content-length': `${length}`,
    },
// Change BASE64 encoded data to a file path with prefix `ReactNativeBlobUtil-file://`.
// Or simply wrap the file path with ReactNativeBlobUtil.wrap(
    ReactNativeBlobUtil.wrap(chunk),
  ).catch(error => console.log({error}));
  console.log({res});
};
const commitBlockList = async (blockIds: any, length: any, url: any) => {
  let blockList: any[] = blockIds?.map(
    (value: string) => `<Latest>${value}</Latest>`,
  );
  let ff = blockList
    .toString()
    .replace('[', '')
    .replace(']', '')
    .replace(',', '\n');
  console.log({url}, {blockList}, {ff});
  const res2 = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fetch(
    'PUT',
    `${url}&comp=blocklist`,
    {
      'x-ms-date': new Date().toUTCString(),
      'content-length': `${length}`,
      'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <BlockList>
      ${ff}
    </BlockList>`,
  )
    .progress((re, t) => console.log({re}, {t}))
    .catch(error => console.log({error}));
  console.log({res2});
};
```

Comment: Can you check the size of the blob? Is it the sum of the size of two blocks? How are you downloading the blob? Are you simply pasting the URL in a browser's address bar? If so, then please check the network trace and see what is being received from the storage service.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks for your answer, size of blob is 1.43MB which is sum of the size of two blocks and yes I simply past the url in browser. I see this error in network status " 400 One of the request inputs is out of range"

Comment: `400 One of the request inputs is out of range` - Are there any more details? Can you share the request and response headers?

Comment: @GauravMantri I add it in question

Comment: I tried loading your blob and it worked fine for me. The 400 error you're getting is for `favicon.ico`.

Comment: So why video is just first block content?

Comment: For me it is showing the response content length as 1508950 bytes which is 1.43MB. Please try to access the blob in some other browser. Could be related to cache.

Comment: I checked it with another browser and also on my phone, summation of two blocks  should be a video with 1minute duration while the returned video is 33seconds which is equal to first block duration @GauravMantri

Comment: You're correct. Indeed the video duration is 33 seconds. This is quite weird!

Comment: @GauravMantri It is and I don't know which part of code is not working correctly. Could this be due to pass wrong body to put block api? which type it should be for video?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. It may very well be an issue with blob upload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254497/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-beginnerprogrammer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @GauravMantri . I change my method to extract chunks and it works fine. Code in the question set video type for each chunk (for example chunk1.mp4) it seems azure storage cannot merge these files. So I store each chunk without type and change code to this, now its working.

```
export const uploadLargeFile = async (param: any) => {
  const {path, filename, mime} = param;
  const blockSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // 1MB
  const fileSize = param?.size;
  const blockCount = Math.ceil(fileSize / blockSize);
  const sasContainerUri = Config.sasContainerUri ;
  const customBlobName = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
  const fileExtension = (filename ?? path).split('.').pop();
  const newFileName = `${customBlobName}.${fileExtension}`;
  const container = 'images';
  const assetPath = `${sasContainerUri}/${container}/${newFileName}`;
  const sasToken = Config.SAS_TOKEN; // you may need to play with other html verbs in this string e.g., `sp`, `ss` e.t.c.
  const blockIds: any[] = [];
  let totalSize = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < blockCount; i++) {
    const blockId = btoa('block-' + i.toString().padStart(6, '0'));
    blockIds.push(blockId);
    const start = i * blockSize;
    const end = Math.min(start + blockSize, fileSize);
    let dest = `${ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.dirs.CacheDir}/RIM3/d3_${i}`;
    let file = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.slice(path, dest, start, end);
    let info = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.stat(file);
    const stageResult = await stageBlock(
      blockId,
      file,
      `${assetPath}?${sasToken}`,
      info?.size,
      i,
      blockCount,
      param?.changeProgress,
    );
    if (!stageResult) {
      showErrorMessage('Error upload file');
      break;
    }
    totalSize += info.size;
    console.log({i});
    if (i === blockCount - 1) {
      const isSuccess = await commitBlockList(
        blockIds,
        fileSize,
        `${assetPath}?${sasToken}`,
      );
      if (isSuccess) {
        return newFileName;
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    }
  }
};
```